# can I use a php method in a form action?

Tags: php, forms

Is it possible to send form data to a PHP class' method rather than to a file?  Or would I have to use AJAX to do this?

For instance, can I have something like:

```
<form action="my_obj::form_submit" method="post">...</form>
//rather than
<form action="my_obj.php" method="post">...</form>
```

I don't want anyone to be able to access the entire file directly.  I don't see a problem having a single public static method that is available, though, because a single method is easy to "harden" for public use.  There is an AJAX function to help me do this, but I think it would be faster to not do that.

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible and would be a horrible, horrible idea. This would mean that anyone could submit die() or something more nefarious and have it executed directly just by changing the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible as the client-side code can **never** know about that kind of server-side implementation detail. As Chuck Vose comments, if that were even possible, it's a major security liability.

`action` attributes on `<form>` elements, like `<a href>`, are simply URIs, so you cannot point to some specific part of a PHP code and expect PHP to assemble everything and run it. Again it's the same client/server side issue.

Unless you use some kind of URL routing like many frameworks provide (per webbiedave's answer), you won't be able to go any further than a URI pointing to a PHP script in your site.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to handle it via a specific uri query. So you can check, whether a key in the `$_GET` variable is given and load the class with a specific method.

Otherwise knowing of a given key in the `$_POST` variable let you forward your process to the method you want to call. So there is no specific need for this kind of form submit call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `action="my_obj::form_submit"` as that's not even a valid URI. However, you can do `action="/my_obj/form_submit"` and map the URI to `/<object>/<method>` This is the approach that many MVC frameworks use.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, this is not done with an MVC.

Comment: Doesn't have to be used in MVC. Was just letting you know that others map URIs to class methods all the time.

Comment: that is interesting... I already started with AJAX.  I may experiment with this in a future project.